# Interpolating a series with float index

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following data frame

```
   density  A2     B2
0       20   1  0.525
1       30   1  0.577
2       40   1  0.789
3       50   1  1.000
4       75   1  1.000
5      100   1  1.000
```

I'm trying yo interpolate the value `value` of column `result_column` using `index_column`.

Lets say `value = 35, result_column = 'B2', index_column= 'density'`

```
result = pd.Series(df[result_column])
try:
   result.index = df[index_column].astype(float)
except ValueError:
   evaluation_error(_("cannot perform interpolation on non numeric index"))
```

Then i append a new row with the index `value`

```
result = result.append(pd.Series(None,index=[value]))
```

and the interpolation

```
result = result.interpolate(method="values")
result = result.loc[value][:1,]
```

This is fails with

```
TypeError: "Cannot cast array data from dtype('O') to dtype('float64') according to the rule 'safe'"
```

The error message here is no mystery. I'm using pandas 0.12 and i know there are problems with float indexes.

Debugging a bit I can also see that the index is created as `object` and not as `float` which prevents interpolation.

```
(Pdb) result.index
Index([20.0, 30.0, 40.0, 50.0, 75.0, 100.0, 0.8], dtype=object)
```

I haven't managed to force the series index to be float or to be able to perform interpolation on the original data frame.

I also tried

```
(Pdb) pd.Series(df[result_column], index=df[index_column])
(Pdb) pd.Series(df[result_column], index=df[index_column].astype(float))
(Pdb) pd.Series(df[result_column], index=pd.Series(df[index_column],dtype=float))
```

all coming back with

```
density
20        NaN
30        NaN
40        NaN
50        NaN
75        NaN
100       NaN
Name: A2, dtype: float64
```

my question is - what is the best why to perform interpolation ?

**EDIT**
following up on @TomAugspurger answer

```
(Pdb) l
249         pdb.set_trace()
250         result = df.set_index(index_column)[result_column]
251         result = result.reindex(result.index + pd.Index([value]))
252         
253  ->     result = result.interpolate(method='values')[value][:1,]
254         return result
(Pdb) result
20     0.630
30     0.692
35       NaN
40     0.947
50     1.200
75     1.200
100    1.200
Name: B2, dtype: float64
(Pdb) result.index
Index([20, 30, 35, 40, 50, 75, 100], dtype=object)
(Pdb) result.interpolate(method='values')
*** TypeError: Cannot cast array data from dtype('O') to dtype('float64') according to the rule 'safe'
```

I dont understand - when running this code in Ipython i'm getting the expected results but during runtime it keeps on failing with this TypeError.

**EDIT2**
the index turned to object because `value` is of type `Decimal`. though i'm not surer why should the value effect the index .... i'll just do a conversion.

Comment: a FloatIndex is of dtype ``object`` (its more straightforward to do comparisons that way). Try this on master; there are many more interpolation options: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/missing_data.html#interpolation

Comment: @Jeff - so you'r saying it should work ? the new `interpolate()` is on 0.13.0.

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to interpolate. I am pointing out that trying to astype the index is not going to work (as its not designed to be of dtype float). Pls read the interpolation docs, they are very complete.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does this work?

```
In [29]: df = df.set_index('density')

In [31]: df = df.reindex(df.index + pd.Index([35]))

In [32]: df
Out[32]: 
     A2     B2
20    1  0.525
30    1  0.577
35  NaN    NaN
40    1  0.789
50    1  1.000
75    1  1.000
100   1  1.000

In [33]: df.interpolate(method='values')
Out[33]: 
     A2     B2
20    1  0.525
30    1  0.577
35    1  0.683
40    1  0.789
50    1  1.000
75    1  1.000
100   1  1.000
```

Comment: hey @TomAugspurger i editedmy question with you answer - still not working. same error.

Comment: What's the type of `density`? at the start?

Comment: `density` is `int64` and `A2` & `B2` are `float64`